# installing android ADT with eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i recently downloaded the android sdk but when i try to create a new android project in eclipse , it always shows the same error

```
[2016-04-15 01:22:40 - HelloWorld3] C:\Users\Admin\workspace\HelloWorld3\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-04-15 01:22:40 - HelloWorld3] 
[2016-04-15 01:22:40 - HelloWorld3] C:\Users\Admin\workspace\HelloWorld3\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-04-15 01:22:40 - HelloWorld3] 
[2016-04-15 01:22:40 - HelloWorld3] C:\Users\Admin\workspace\HelloWorld3\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2016-04-15 01:22:40 - HelloWorld3]
```

the project is not created. i was using eclipse luna before, i reinstalled eclipse and now i have mars 2. i also deleted the latest packages from SDK manager. these are the only solutions i have found

another thing that i noticed is that eclipse is not working as it should after installing android sdk. for example the icon doesnt change. in the welcome page after installing sdk, it does not give me the option to choose from existing SDKs. when i click File -> New , there is no android application project, and i have to select project then click on android and then android application project.
can someone pls help ??

Comment: I would recommend looking into Android Studio unless you have a requirement/restriction keeping you locked into Eclipse. Android Studio is the supported IDE for Android development.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the support project ....

Do this:

1. File -> Import (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7).  And there choose "**appcompat**"
2. Project -> properties -> Android.  In  the  section library "Add" and choose "**appCompat**"

[image]

Comment: i dont have the extras folder

Answer (score 0):

To be honest with you, you will have less headache if you start using Android Studio, since it is now the official IDE for andoid and you recieve all the latest updates pretty much automatically. But if you Really have to work with Eclipse for some reason thats how you do it:

1. File -> Import (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7). And there choose "appcompat"
2. Project -> properties -> Android. In the section library "Add" and choose "appCompat"

The error says you that you are missing "appCompat".
I said pretty much same that @ΦXoce 웃 Пepeúpa did but really consider going to Android Studio.